# What is the [image] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [image](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) tag currently has no description. Is it for questions that contain an image, questions that request images, or both? Are there any other use cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [single question (formerly) with that tag](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/42/13), it seems it was meant for the "Image Recall Technique" (whatever that is).

It seems to me the [image](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) tag should not exist.  As such, I have removed that tag, and added [image-recall-technique](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-recall-technique) in its place.